# UWP FaceDetector accuracy

Tags: c#, uwp, face-recognition

Has anyone been able to get even a modicum of accuracy out of the FaceDetector class that ships with UWP?

Cognitive services seems to be pretty accurate, but the FaceDetector class itself is next to useless.  Using the Sample code: https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/BasicFaceDetection and trying my own pictures, I'm getting an accuracy rate of about 5%.  Out of 42 photos with faces, it never manages to find more than one, and it misses all faces altogether in most.

I have a feeling the GrayScale conversion that appears "necessary" (there's no other accepted format) renders it mostly useless.  For comparison, cognitive services found faces accurately in those same 42 photos about 95% of the time.

I have to think MSFT wouldn't ship code that's this error prone.

Has anyone had success with this class?  What changes did you have to make?

Thanks!

Comment: I tried the sample, I got a result like this [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hmlSx.png).  Seems  it is accurate . I tested on Lumia 950 build 15204.  Could you please provide your test environment? And may be one of the photos cannot be recognized.

Comment: They're all personal photos.  A lot of them are taken in the Grand Canyon and Zion National Park, so I googled for that and found: http://www.mfeltphotography.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/20150421-IMG_0796.jpg. (personal photos are closer up/higher res) This fails as well.  The other thing I just realized is that the majority of the photos that fail to detect faces completely get rendered in the wrong orientation in the BasicFaceDetection sample app.  For example upside or turned 90 degrees.